# req.user undefined in webhook get request

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, passport.js, webhooks

My App is getting a webhook. The webhook is triggering a get request to my backend. The get request needs the current req.user object to get the user credentials and perform necessary functions to "list" this users conversation.

When I trigger the get request from my frontend to the backend everything works fine, However when I trigger the function from a webhook my req.user is undefined.

How do you get credentials when using webhooks?

Here is the function being called

````
    const listConversationMessages = async (req, res) => {
        console.log("list conversation Messages triggered")
        console.log(req.body)
        const { subActServiceSid, subActAuthToken, convoServiceSid} = req.user // this is undefined when using webhook but fine when calling from front end
        const subClient = require('twilio')(subActServiceSid, subActAuthToken)
        const allConversationSids = []
        const allMessages = []
        const sortedMessages = []
        const options = { weekday: 'long'}
        const monthOptions = { month: 'long'}
       

        await subClient.conversations.services(convoServiceSid)
        .conversations
        .list()
        .then(conversations => conversations.forEach(c => allConversationSids.push(c.sid))); // conversation possibly has "read" property?
        await Promise.all(allConversationSids.map( async (convo) => {
           await subClient.conversations.services(convoServiceSid)
           .conversations(convo)
           .messages
           .list({limit: 20})
           .then(messages => messages.forEach(m => allMessages.push({"messagesId": m.conversationSid, "participantSid": m.participantSid,  "message": m.body, "time": { "day": new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(m.dateCreated.getDay()), "hour": m.dateCreated.getHours() + ":" + m.dateCreated.getMinutes(), "date": new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', monthOptions).format(m.dateCreated.getMonth()) + " " + m.dateCreated.getDate() + ", " + m.dateCreated.getFullYear()}})));
        }))
       let response
        if(allMessages.length < 1 ) {
        response = [{"messagesId": 1 , "content": [{ "participantSid": 2,  "message": "test"} ]}]
        } else {
        response = allMessages
    }
   
    result = await response.reduce(function (accumulator, indexOfObject) {
        accumulator[indexOfObject.messagesId] = accumulator[indexOfObject.messagesId] || [];
        accumulator[indexOfObject.messagesId].push(indexOfObject);       //it generates a new property a.messagesId with an array if it does not exist (the value of not existing properties is undefined). if exist, it assign itself
        return accumulator;
    }, Object.create({}));
  
    sortedMessages.push(result)
    const finalResult = Object.entries(sortedMessages[0]).map(([id, content]) => ({ id, content }))
    res.json(finalResult)
       }```
````

Comment: Can you share how to request looks like when using the webhook?

Comment: should I console.log(req) and post it here?

Comment: Yes. But also show us how the request itself looks, before you send it.